# Could not enable plugin with error: requires SSO SAML realm configuration to be modified and must be included in the deployment payload

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-cloud, elastic-plugin

I tried to enable an analysis plugin in the elastic cloud, eventually, I got back the following error after I clicked Save

```
Your changes cannot be applied

The [enterprise_search] resource [main-enterprise_search] requires SSO SAML realm configuration to be modified and must be included in the deployment payload
Add analysis-kuromoji plugin
```

You can see the error dialog below

[image]

did I miss any configuration or do I need to do anything else before being able to enable an extra analysis plugin?

Can anyone explain to me how to solve this problem?